# How to insert data to the same table id with Javascript Clone Code?

Tags: javascript, django

I am trying something with django and i need clone the form elements.
I found some code, it works but it inserts the different table id. I wanna clone two form fields with js clone code. It clones and then post the fields, when i looked the database, i see two fields inserterd tho different ids. How can i fix this?

When you look database image, same numbers but different id's. How can i insert data to same id with two form fields.

This is create_normal.html

[image]

Here is the database

[image]

Here is my codes.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.





class PatientBilgi(models.Model):
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=155)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class PatientAliskanlik(models.Model):
    
    sigara = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    alkol = models.CharField(max_length=155)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sigara



class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    pbilgi = models.ForeignKey(PatientBilgi, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    palis = models.ForeignKey(PatientAliskanlik, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    
    def __int__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import  Patient, PatientBilgi, PatientAliskanlik
from django.forms import (formset_factory, modelformset_factory)



class PatientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = Patient
        fields = ['name']



class PatientBilgiForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = PatientBilgi
        fields = ['name', 'surname']



class PatientAliskanlikForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = PatientAliskanlik
        fields = ['sigara', 'alkol']        



###### Formsets


class PatientBilgiModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = PatientBilgi
        fields = ('name', 'surname' )
        labels = {
            'name': 'Patient Name',
            'surname': 'Patient  Surname'
        }
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Enter Patient Name and Surname here'
                }
            )
        }


PatientBilgiFormset = formset_factory(PatientBilgiForm)
BookModelFormset = modelformset_factory(
    PatientBilgi,
    fields=('name', 'surname', ),
    extra=1,
    widgets={
        'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Enter Patient Name here'
            }
        ),
        'surname': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Enter Patient Surname here'
            }
        )
    }
)



PatientFormset = modelformset_factory(
    Patient,
    fields=('name', ),
    extra=1,
    widgets={'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Enter Author Name here'
        })
    }
)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect 
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import Patient, PatientBilgi, PatientAliskanlik
from .forms import PatientForm, PatientBilgiForm, PatientAliskanlikForm, PatientBilgiFormset, PatientBilgiModelForm, PatientFormset
from formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')



def hasta_listele(request):
    data =  Patient.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'deneme.html', {'data': data})


def hasta_detay(request, id):
    kata = Patient.objects.get(id=id)
    kata1 = PatientBilgi.objects.get(id=id)
    kata2 = PatientAliskanlik.objects.get(id=id)

    return render(request, 'hasta_detay.html', 
    context = {
    'kata': kata, 
    'kata1': kata1,
    'kata2': kata2}
    )


# Multi Step Form Submission

class multistepformsubmission(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = 'hasta_kayit.html'
    form_list = [PatientBilgiForm, PatientAliskanlikForm, PatientForm]

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]
        

        patientdata = PatientBilgi(name = form_data[0]['name'], surname = form_data[0]['surname'])
        patientdata.save() 

        patientdata1 = PatientAliskanlik(sigara = form_data[1]['sigara'], alkol = form_data[1]['alkol'])
        patientdata1.save() 

        patientdata2 = Patient(name = form_data[2]['name'] )
        patientdata2.save()
       

        data = Patient.objects.all()
        data1 = PatientBilgi.objects.all()
        data2 = PatientAliskanlik.objects.all() 

        return render(self.request, 'done.html', context={
            'data': data,
            'data1': data1,
            'data2': data2
            
            
            })

######## Deneme Amaçlı Fonksiyon, gereği yok....

def deneme(request):
    a = Patient.objects.all()
    return render(request, "a.html", {'a': a })

##################

########## Formset Fonskiyonu


def create_book_normal(request):
    template_name = 'create_normal.html'
    
    if request.method == 'GET':
        formset = PatientBilgiFormset(request.GET or None)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        formset = PatientBilgiFormset(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                name = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
                surname = form.cleaned_data.get('surname')
                # save book instance
                if name:
                    PatientBilgi(name=name).save()
                    PatientBilgi(surname=surname).save()
            return redirect('done')

    return render(request, template_name, {
        'formset': formset,
        
    })



def done1(request):
    return render(request, 'done.html')
```

create_normal.html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
<div class="row form-row spacer">
    <div class="col-2">
        <label>{{form.name.label}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="input-group">
            {{form.name}}
            {{form.surname}}

            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-success add-form-row">+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
<div class="row spacer">
    <div class="col-4 offset-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Create</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateElementIndex(el, prefix, ndx) {
    var id_regex = new RegExp('(' + prefix + '-\\d+)');
    var replacement = prefix + '-' + ndx;
    if ($(el).attr("for")) $(el).attr("for", $(el).attr("for").replace(id_regex, replacement));
    if (el.id) el.id = el.id.replace(id_regex, replacement);
    if (el.name) el.name = el.name.replace(id_regex, replacement);
}
function cloneMore(selector, prefix) {
    var newElement = $(selector).clone(true);
    var total = $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
    newElement.find(':input:not([type=button]):not([type=submit]):not([type=reset])').each(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('name')
        if(name) {
            name = name.replace('-' + (total-1) + '-', '-' + total + '-');
            var id = 'id_' + name;
            $(this).attr({'name': name, 'id': id}).val('').removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });
    newElement.find('label').each(function() {
        var forValue = $(this).attr('for');
        if (forValue) {
          forValue = forValue.replace('-' + (total-1) + '-', '-' + total + '-');
          $(this).attr({'for': forValue});
        }
    });
    total++;
    $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(total);
    $(selector).after(newElement);
    var conditionRow = $('.form-row:not(:last)');
    conditionRow.find('.btn.add-form-row')
    .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
    .removeClass('add-form-row').addClass('remove-form-row')
    .html('-');
    return false;
}
function deleteForm(prefix, btn) {
    var total = parseInt($('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val());
    if (total > 1){
        btn.closest('.form-row').remove();
        var forms = $('.form-row');
        $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(forms.length);
        for (var i=0, formCount=forms.length; i<formCount; i++) {
            $(forms.get(i)).find(':input').each(function() {
                updateElementIndex(this, prefix, i);
            });
        }
    }
    return false;
}
$(document).on('click', '.add-form-row', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    cloneMore('.form-row:last', 'form');
    return false;
});
$(document).on('click', '.remove-form-row', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    deleteForm('form', $(this));
    return false;
});

</script>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way there is no need javascript. Actually i wanna make multiple forms and each datas must belong to one register. And sometimes one register can be own multiple datas. After all searching i found another way to make my project. I made a model with a primary key and then i give foreignkey and onetonefield to other models. Everything solved.
Here is the full project code: https://github.com/eseymenler/demo2